# How to move 1st textarea content to 2nd textarea on button click P(paragraph)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to move 1st textarea content to 2nd textarea on button click P(paragraph). on button click p it should add as paragraph in 2nd textarea. How to achieve this in javascript or jquery?
How to create custom texteditor with inline edit and delete button, here the inline edit is for 2nd textarea content.

Comment: Hi , first_textarea value should be entered second textarea as a paragraph on button click and it includes dynamic edit and delete button.if we place cursor on second text area , when we add first textarea value in secondtextarea it should add the value as a paragraph on the cursor place of second textarea. In second textarea if we click delete the paragraph should get deleted and on click of edit we can edit the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#paragraph').on('click', function() {
        var first_para_text = $('#first_textarea').val();
    $('#second_textarea').val(first_para_text);
    $('#second_textarea').prop('disabled', true);
});

$('#edit').on('click', function() {
        $('#second_textarea').prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#reset').on('click', function() {
        $('#second_textarea').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>first text area</label>
      <textarea id="first_textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label>second text area</label>
      <textarea id="second_textarea" disabled></textarea>
      <button id="edit">
      Edit
      </button>
      <button id="reset">
      Reset
      </button>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <button id="paragraph">
      Transfer Text
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Considering the lack of information on the question it self, and the help needed to explain the requirement, you've done pretty good job at providing a working example, but keeping the answer the same as the question, unparallelly and undesirably un explainable, please try to add more info the answer, so others would get to know more